# How to loop through txt file and then replace bad words in iOS

Tags: objective-c, regex, string, parsing, nsregularexpression

Hello I'm new to iOS and im trying to loop through a txt file that I have imported to a Textview and then replace "bad words" with "Better words" I have three arrays 1 holding the txt file that is converted to an array. They list of bad words that it should look for and the list of good words in which they should be replaced with. The program should be able to scan the text and look for bad words and according to the value of the bad word replace it with a better word. This is what I have so far when scanning the text. I'm trying to test to see if bad words are recognized and right now this doesn't work.

```
- (IBAction)scanText:(id)sender

{

    NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];


    NSArray *lines =  [contents componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSArray *badword = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Objectivity",@"people",nil];
    NSArray *goodWord = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Default", @"Creepers"];



            for (NSString* bad in badword)

                if ([lines containsObject: bad])
                {
                    self.textView.text = [textFile stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:bad withString:@"##"];
                }


}
```

Comment: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/2667634/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-When-obscenity-filters-go-wrong.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `NSRegularExpression`. Mind you, I haven't thought a bunch about how the regex should be, but this should work for most cases.

**EDIT:** I missed the replacement part. Here is with replacement:

```
NSString *string = @"This is a paragraph with bad words that we don't want!!";
NSArray *badwords = @[@"bad", @"words"];
NSArray *betterwords = @[@"good", @"something"];

NSMutableString *pattern = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"([^A-Za-z]?)("];
NSString *pipe = @"";
for (NSString *badWord in badwords)
{
    [pattern appendString:pipe];
    [pattern appendString:badWord];

    pipe = @"|";
}

[pattern appendString:@")([^A-Za-z]?)"];

NSMutableString *finalString = [string mutableCopy];

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:nil];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:string
                        options:0
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

                         NSRange badrange = [result rangeAtIndex:2];
                         NSString *badword = [string substringWithRange:badrange];
                         NSInteger index = [badwords indexOfObject:badword];
                         NSString *betterword = betterwords[index];

                         NSInteger offset = finalString.length - string.length;
                         badrange.location += offset;

                         [finalString replaceCharactersInRange:badrange withString:betterword];
                     }];

NSLog(@"%@", finalString);
```

result:

```
2014-06-18 [71719:60b] This is a paragraph with good something that we don't want!!
```

Anyways, I am not really trying to solve the regex problem, but the Objective-C problem of how to tackle this problem.